# Crashes occurring on MacBook Pro 16"

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

I got several crashes on my Mac.

They all have the same feature of **no successful checkins from remoted in 180 seconds**. What is that stuff that was not timeout? Any strategies for resolving that kind of problem?

> panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff800e56799f): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful
> checkins from remoted in 180 seconds
> service returned not alive with context : is_alive_func returned unhealthy : device not
> connected (code: 0x2 service: logd, total successful checkins since
> wake (12540 seconds ago): 1255, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
> service: WindowServer, total successful checkins since wake (12540
> seconds ago): 1255, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago service:
> remoted, total successful checkins since wake (12540 seconds ago):
> 1228, last successful checkin: 180 seconds ago service:
> opendirectoryd, total successful checkins since wake (12540 seconds
> ago): 1255, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago

Comment: What is a Mac 16?

Comment: Pardon a MacBook Pro 16

Comment: And which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Latest one. That kind of errors occurred starting with BigSur but continuing till yesterday. A limitation to 180 seconds for some process that lead to a crash.